# Can I create a vector of threads and use to process data concurrently from database table in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, vector

`Can I create a vector of threads in java
Vector threads = new Vector<>(5);

And assign them to process data from database concurrently

I want to make a Java program where main method first check how many active threads are there in the vector and pull that amount of data from the database and process those data and then main thread will go to sleep for 10 seconds
After waking up from the sleep the main thread will how many threads are free at this moment Let's say there are 3 threads are free at this moment so the main thread will pull next 3 data from the database

Can someone please help me to build the logic and design to implement this in java
It would be a great help `

```java
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

                        String selectQuery = "SELECT dataName, dataItem FROM thread";
  PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(selectQuery);                              
                        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

                        while (rs.next()) {
                            String dataName = rs.getString("dataName");
                            String dataItem = rs.getString("dataItem");
                            for (DataProcessingThread thread : threadVector) {
                                if (!thread.isProcessing()) {
                                    thread.setData(dataName, dataItem);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }`
This is database connection
```

Comment: and why on earth would you want to use a vector, a class that is so obsolete?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Go ahead and code something, once you have a problem come back here and ask it then.

Comment: I tried to clean up your code formatting, but it needs more work. Take more care when posting here.

Answer (score 4):

[`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Vector.html) is a [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) class, as noted in its Javadoc, invented before the [Java Collections Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework). Instead use a [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) implementation, such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html).

But for your purpose, use something else. Use an [executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to manage threads on your behalf.

> check how many active threads

Your desired work to be done (tasks) drives the use of threads, not the other way around.

Define your tasks as a `Runnable` or `Callable` object. Then submit to an executor service for execution on a background thread.

If you want to query your database repeatedly, use a [scheduled executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to repeat a `Runnable`/`Callable` task. Within that task, query the database. If you find records in the database that need to be processed, instantiate `Runnable`/`Callable` objects for that purpose, and submit to another executor service. In Java 21+, assuming your tasks are not entirely [CPU-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound), generally best to use an [executor service backed by virtual threads](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()).

> assign them to process data from database concurrently

Just establish an executor service instance, submit one or more tasks (`Runnable`/`Callable` objects), and then automatically close the executor service with try-with-resources syntax. This has been shown [several times already](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20ExecutorService%20try-with-resources%20syntax&tts=st_asaf_macos) on Stack Overflow.

---

By the way, `Class.forName` has not been needed for many years now. In modern Java, all the JDBC drivers are automatically loaded by the [Java Service Provider Interface (SPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface).

Tip: Learn to set up your database connection info (username, password, etc.) within an object implementing the [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) interface.

Overall, it sounds like you are working off an ancient tutorial. Find more recent materials to study. Also, you can find many existing Questions and Answers on all these topics mentioned here.

Comment: Can we maintain threads by using executor service?

Comment: @Polash I have no idea what you mean by "maintain threads".

Comment: Can we check how many threads are currently free in executor service?

Comment: @Polash You do not care about threads being free/available. You submit tasks to the executor service. That service sees to it that your tasks get scheduled on threads for eventual execution.

Comment: @Polash You have not carefully delineated your actual goal, so I cannot outline any logic in more detail than I already have. I suggest you spend some time learning about how threading works, and about how to use an executor service. Again, search Stack Overflow to find many existing Answers on that topic as well as complete examples of interacting with a database in JDBC.

Comment: @Polash Tip: Search Stack Overflow using a search engine such as Bing or Google. The search feature within the StackOverflow.com web site is weak and flawed. For [example](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20ScheduledExecutorService&tts=st_asaf_macos).

Comment: I want o make fixed number of threads initially. Let's say we have created 5 threads. At First the main method pull 5 data and give the 5 threads to process. Different threads take different amount of time to process. Let's say after giving the 5 data main thread goes to sleep for 10 seconds and after waking up it saw that 2 threads have done processing so now main method will  pull 2 data from database and give them to the 2 currently available threads. Can we Build this logic in executor service?

Comment: @Polash You're missing the point, the executor service can be configured with a fixed number or a pool of threads - beyond that, you don't care, just pass work to the executor and let it run.  You make use of `Future`s and/or wait for the current tasks to complete executing and then do more work

Comment: @Polash Submit *all* your tasks to the executor service. The executor service then assigns those tasks to available threads, one after another, just as you described.